# Dreamweaver dialogue boxes are huge and i can't fix it

Tags: windows, dreamweaver, dpi

When opening a dialogue box within dreamweaver, for example the dreamweaver preferences windows, or CSS editor window, it appears very large, almost twice the size of my screen.

For example: 
Screenshot:

[image]

I have checked my systems DPI Settings and they are set to 100%.

Im running windows 8.1. 
My screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Any ideas?

Comment: would this be better asked on superuser.com?

Comment: ANSWER: I managed to fix this issue by deleting all of my fonts and replacing them with a fresh download from here: http://www.withsteps.com/2621/windows-8-default-font-download-repair-kit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: I managed to fix this issue by deleting all of my fonts and replacing them with a fresh download from here: http://www.withsteps.com/2621/windows-8-default-font-download-repair-kit.html